# Should a unique constraint be set both in the model and the database?

Tags: sql, database, validation, orm, migration

I'm building an application using the MVC pattern using ORM, and I'm struggling to understand what the 'best practice' for setting default values and constraints in the models and the migration (database).

Is it recommended to set validations both in the model and the database or just one of them? And if the latter, which one?

Answer (score 0):

When constraints are set in the database, they are enforced regardless of whether the database is accessed via the application you're building now or via some other interactive or programmatic interface.  Constraints set in the database therefore give you more robust protection of data integrity.

Comment: That makes sense. Such a good idea. But why would you bother adding constraints in the models in addition to that, why not just keep it DRY and not repeat yourself?

Comment: I wouldn't bother applying constraints in the ORM if they are set in the database.  However, I almost never use an ORM because DBMS features and SQL are more powerful, and just as easy to use with a few custom methods added to the database connector.

Comment: but there are no downsides adding the constraints in the models too?

Comment: Probably there's a little performance hit, because the ORM will duplicate integrity checks that the DBMS will do.  But there should be no data integrity downside.